# Remove visual composer shortcode

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm trying to remove all unnecessary shortcodes from visual composer with some `preg_replace`. E.g. there is some elements like this:

```
[vc_row][/vc_row][vc_row el_class="hidepdf]
```

The best way would be to remove anything between `[]` starting with `vc_` and followed by anything until the end bracket `]`

I've tried it with following RegEx:

```
/\[[\/]?vc_*[^\]]\]/
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: why are you using visual composer, if you are not using it's shortcodes? also, where are you adding that code? in your functions.php?

Comment: Your regex is wrong. You have to escape the square brackets you want to match and the forward slash (within /.../) must be escaped too.
try something like /\[\/?vc_row(?: .*?)\]/

Comment: You can test your preg_replace on www.phpliveregex.com

Comment: Oh I just realized SO removed my escaping backslashes...
Just think if you still need Visual Composer. If not, remove it...
Your way of doing it is not great.

Comment: I'm generating pdf documents with dk_pdf and "translate" some VC shortcodes but I want to remove the rest.

Comment: I developed a free WordPress plugin to solve this problem, the plugin named ( Shortcode Cleaner Lite ) https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-cleaner-lite/ It provides an easy way to clean up unused, broken shortcodes from WordPress content automatically, so you can switch between themes and plugins without worrying, it is dealing with any theme (Divi, Avada…etc) shortcodes that are left when changing themes or plugins or page builders (Visual Composer, Divi…etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex `"/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/"`

Comment: do you have any idea how to change
[vc_row el_class="hidepdf"]  => to <div class="hidepdf"> with preg_replace

Comment: Great it worked for you. I had tested this with regex before I submitted it here. I dont know why someone downvoted it though. I only gave regex because that exactly what you seemed to be looking for.

Comment: This shoudl work for that replace: `$div = preg_replace("/\[vc_row(.*?)el_class=\"(.*?)\"\]/", "<div class='$2'>", $str); ` Replace $str with your input string of course.

Answer (score 1):

To remove unnecessary wpbakery shortcodes from your WordPress content, you can use a custom function in your theme's functions.php file. Here's how you can do it:

```
function remove_unnecessary_shortcodes($content) {
$pattern = '/\[\/?vc_[^\]]*\]/';
$replacement = '';
$new_content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
return $new_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_unnecessary_shortcodes');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($posts->have_posts()) {
      $postContent = get_the_content();
      //Remove visual composer tags [vc_column] etc
      $postContent = preg_replace( "/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/", '', $postContent );
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide some textual explanation what this snipper of code should be solving related to the question?

Comment: Please add some explanation of your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can just remove the content in the admin control panel.
Why should you replace the content, rofl.

But if you very-very need:

```
$start = preg_quote('[vc_row]', '/');
$end = preg_quote('[/vc_row]', '/');
$content = preg_replace("/$start.*$end/imsU", '', $content);
```