# Removing text from a CSV using sed

Tags: regex, csv, sed

**Context:** I have a csv file containing a products export from prestashop and I need to remove every occurence of any visual composer shortcode inside of it.

I found this regex `"/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/"` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455667/remove-visual-composer-shortcode)) that can help.

Now I'm tring to use `sed` with that and I built this one line command but it not working at all (option of s unknown).

```
sed -i -E "s\/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]//\g" origin.csv
```

What am i missing?

Edit:
The problem is in the Product Description column:
e.g.

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]
ADULT GRAIN FREE
[/vc_column_text][vc_separator color="grey"][vc_column_text]
RICETTA COMPLETA PER CANI ADULTI DI TUTTE LE RAZZE
[/vc_column_text][vc_separator color="grey"][vc_column_text]
65% DI CARNE FRESCA DI POLLO, FRUTTA & VERDURA
```

That is full of this [vc_row] and similar.
A desired output will be like this:

```
ADULT GRAIN FREE
RICETTA COMPLETA PER CANI ADULTI DI TUTTE LE RAZZE
65% DI CARNE FRESCA DI POLLO, FRUTTA & VERDURA
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `sed` does not know `*?` (non-greedy) syntax.

Comment: Added an example as requested

Comment: You are backslash-escaping the slashes which should not be escaped, too.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, but your samples of input and expected output is not clear yet, could you please do mention is it you want to print next line fter a match found? You said its a csv file but your shown samples doesn't look like csv format, kindly elaborate more on it, thank you.

Comment: There are some pitfalls with `sed -i`, check against https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171648/sed-gives-sed-cant-read-no-such-file-or-directory/43453459#43453459 (admittedly one of my answers).

Comment: Your sample doesn't look like CSV at all (but it doesn't really matter here; but perhaps the question would be more useful to future visitors if it didn't falsely claim to be about CSV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` does not support non-greedy matching. The regex dialect supported by `sed` is rather primitive, and far predates the Perl features which are now supported in many regex implementations.

The simple fix is to switch to Perl:

```sh
perl -pi -e 's%\[/?vc_(.*?)\]%%g' origin.csv
```

Notice the switch to alternate delimiters to avoid the need to backslash slashes.  You were backslash-escaping the slashes which should not be escaped, too!

It's not impossible to do this in `sed`, either.  Just be more specific about what you want.  Non-greedy matching is often a lazy (sic) way to avoid saying what you really mean.

```sh
sed -i -E "s%\[/?vc_[^][]*\]%%g" origin.csv
```

The updated regex says there can be anything except square brackets in the match after `vc_` which is presumably what you wanted to say all along.

I'm also assuming there can't really be multiple slashes before `vc_` and so we simply say `/?` to indicate one slash max, optional.

Nothing here is specific to CSV; this should work for any text file (though to be really correct, you would need a more complex regex to cover corner cases like a `vc_` code with a comma inside it; but let's just assume you don't have any).